# An Image as a Int Array Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, processing, videochat

I'm using `JMyron` in a webcam app written in Java, and the program returns what the webcam is seeing as an `int []`. Since it's one pixel per int, how does it represent the `rgb` values of the pixel as one int?

Comment: Have you checked the relevant [documentation](http://webcamxtra.sourceforge.net/reference.shtml)?

Comment: @adarshr Reading that documentation is an exercise not for the faint of heart.  From examples included elsewhere on that site, though, it appears that he int values returned by the image() method do indeed represent RGB values as elsewhere represented in Java.  It was merely their explanation which was missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An int is 32 bits. So the first 8 bits of the int are red 0-255, the second 8 bits are green 0-255, the third 8 bits are blue 0-255, and the last 8 bits are the alpha value 0-255.

That's why it's called 32-bit color. It blew my mind when I first connected the dots.

Answer (score 4):

Java's Color can do so as well:

['Color.getRGB()'](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB%28%29)

Different bits of the int represent the different color component values. You may extract them yourself, or use the Color class to do so:

```
Color c = new Color(imageRGB);
int red = c.getRed();
int green = c.getGreen();
...
```